# How to read an image file from sdcard and get it to the src of a img tag in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to read an image from the sdcard which is not taken by the phone camera and get the image src to show on my app. I tried many solutions to this and got many updates. But still it's not working. Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess);
}
function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("test.jpg", {create: false, exclusive: false}, fileSuccess);
}

function fileSuccess(fileEntry){
    fileEntry.file(gotfile);
}

function gotFile(file){
    readDataUrl(file);  
}

function readDataUrl(file){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onlaodend=function(evt){
        console.log(evt.target.result); 
        document.getElementById("img_test").src=evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

and I am trying to get this src of img:

```
<div>
    <img id="img_test" src="">
</div>
```

Is there anything wrong with the filepath? I am new to phonegap. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example this helps you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pick Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onFail);
    }

     function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("1.jpg", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);  
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
           console.log("Read as data URL");
           console.log(evt.target.result);
           document.getElementById("smallImage").style.display='block'; 
           document.getElementById("smallImage").src = evt.target.result;   
        }; 
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This will allow you to pick any specified image from sdcard.

Comment: I saw this code before and mainly was working on it. But still it's not working. If you go over my code again, you will see that my code is pretty much similar to this. Can you tell me where I am doing wrong here please?? Thanks for the reply..:)

Comment: This code works fine for me. what error you are getting in console? can you please tell..